# Advantage of using @Output instead of using @Input which accepts a function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

What is the advantage of using `@Output property = new EventEmitter();` decorator with the event emitter instance when the same functionality can be achieved with `@Input property: () => void`

and then can pass the method from the parent class,

```
<selector [property]="parentMethod()">
```

Also, while doing output binding when @Output decorator is used,

```
<selector (property)="parentMethod()">
```

Does it internally subscribe to `property` event emitter instance? This only seems to be beneficial when Angular is using the same instance of a component class at multiple places (does this happen? ), couldn't think of any other reason.

Would like to understand the work which Angular is doing behind the scene and which of the above-mentioned approach is better and why?

Comment: In the `@Input` binding case, the syntax must be `<selector [property]="f">`. Both approaches are valid and, while it is rare, sometimes accepting a function as an input binding is useful. However, the differences are not insignificant including the type of the property, the meaning of `this` in the function passed in, following common idioms, and much more.